# Change image on mouseover based on number of times the user has previously performed a mouseover on that image

Tags: mouseover

I have an image, which I would like to change on mouseover, but to a different image each time the user hovers to a count of 4.

For example: The original image is img_black.jpg.

1st mouseouver: 
The image changes to img_blue.jpg.  On mouseout it changes it back to img_black.

2nd mouseouver: 
The image changes to img_red.jpg.  On mouseout it changes it back to img_black.

3rd mouseouver: 
The image changes to img_yellow.jpg.  On mouseout it changes it back to img_black.

4th mouseouver: 
The image changes to img_green.jpg.  On mouseout it changes it back to img_black.

5th mouseouver: 
The image changes to img_blue.jpg.  On mouseout it changes it back to img_black. (The cycle starts over)

I can change the names to img_1, img_2, etc if it makes it easy to use the number from a counter, and reset to 1 when > 4.  Aside from this concept, not sure where to begin...

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: what system is this on?  what programming language are you using?

Comment: Web on an Apache server.  Using HTML and javascript.

Comment: I guess if I had played around with the code more, I would'nt have posted this question.

Sharing, in case it helps anyone else...<script>
var n = 0;
function mouseOver(imgID)
 {
  n += 1;
   document.getElementById(imgID).src = "img/" + imgID + "_" + n + ".jpg";
  if (n>3)
  {
   n=0;
  }
 }

function mouseOut(imgID)
 {
  document.getElementById(imgID).src = "img/" + imgID + "_0.jpg";
 }
</script>

<a href="http://www.hello.com"><img id="picture" src="img/picture_0.jpg" onmouseover = "mouseOver('picture')" onmouseout="mouseOut('picture')"/></a>

Comment: for future reference this question title could have been "Incrementally change image on mouseover using javascript"

Answer (score 0):

Aside from building it all into a component, that's basically it. 
If it were me I'd be looking at a an array/list of Images and a state 
So State 0 would be the not overImage (black in your example)
If there were no other images it would leave it like that.
If there were then State would cycle through 1 - Images.Count - 1 and be the index into the list.
Without knowing the language environment, it's hard to say more.

Answer (score 0):

I gess you are talking about HTML, right? In that case have a look at jQuery. You will need it in order to do that. 
http://jquery.com/